# Xcode 12.4 - Project Compile issue - using Swift 5.2.4 Toolchain (using MacBook M1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-m1

I want to use my existing project in my new MacBook Air M1. Actually my project was running on **Xcode 11.4**. But MacBook Air M1 comes with BigSur OS and it is not possible to downgrade to Catalina OS. So I installed **Swift 5.2.4** Toolchain. After that most of the compiles issues are resolved. Still few files inside that pod folder are having compile errors.

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
```

Compile Error

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___isOSVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
      -[FBSDKAppEvents appendInstallTimestamp:] in FBSDKAppEvents.o
      ___43-[FBSDKAppEvents fetchServerConfiguration:]_block_invoke_2 in FBSDKAppEvents.o
      +[FBSDKAppEventsUtility advertiserID] in FBSDKAppEventsUtility.o
      +[FBSDKAppEventsUtility shouldDropAppEvent] in FBSDKAppEventsUtility.o
      -[FBSDKBridgeAPI applicationDidBecomeActive:] in FBSDKBridgeAPI.o
      -[FBSDKBridgeAPI application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] in FBSDKBridgeAPI.o
      -[FBSDKBridgeAPI _updateAuthStateIfSystemAlertToUseWebAuthFlowPresented] in FBSDKBridgeAPI.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to run that project with iPhone 11 (14.4)simulator. Now I am getting different error

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/lib/swift/Swift.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:21432:21: Module 'Builtin' has no member named 'convertUnownedUnsafeToGuaranteed'
```